# What is the cause of this error I am receiving from a react frontend to a flask backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I have a flask backend running with an api to handle logins with jwt's. The flask function is as follows:

```py
@user.route('/login')
# @cross_origin()
def login():
    email = request.args.get("email", None)
    password = request.args.get("password", None)

    stored_user = User.query.get(email)
    if stored_user != None and check_password_hash(stored_user.password, password):
        print('logged in')

        access_token = create_access_token(identity=email)
        resp = jsonify({'login': True, 'Error': 'User Authentication Success'})

        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)

        return "hello", 200
    
    print("failed to login")
    return jsonify({'login': False, 'Error': 'User Authentication Failed'})
```

It appears to create the token without issue, and respond successfully. The problem arises from the react frontend. Which at the moment is as follows:

```jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Stack from "react-bootstrap/Stack";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export default function Login() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [response, setResponse] = useState({})

    function validate(email, password) {
        if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    function submit() {
        if (validate(email, password)) {
            var api_url = "http://localhost:5000/api/user/login?email=" + email + "&password=" + password
            console.log("The url:", api_url)
            fetch(api_url)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("res:", res)
                    return res.json()
                })
                .then(res => setResponse(res))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        } else {
            console.log("login does not meet requirements")
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(3)
        if (Object.keys(response).length === 0) {
            console.log("no response")
        } else {
            if (response.login === false) {
                // display "incorrect email or password"
                console.log("response:", response)
                console.log("incorrect login")
            } else {
                // redirect to wherever
                console.log("logged in")
            }
        }
    }, [response])

    return (
        <div className="Login">
             <Form onSubmit={submit}>
                <Stack gap={3}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="email">
                        <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            autoFocus
                            size="lg"
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="password">
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            size="lg"
                            type="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(p) => setPassword(p.target.value)}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button size="lg" type="submit">
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Stack>
             </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The HTML awaits a submit action, at which it executes the submit function. The submit function awaits a response via fetch from the flask api point /login. To handle fetch being "async", I await the return and set response to the response. When response is changed, the useEffect function is executed logging the appropriate message. The problem is that I am: a) always when logging in with valid credentials, b) sometimes when logging in with invalid credentials which throw the correct response at other times; receiving this error thrown by the fetch catch:

[image: Error visible in google console]

Why am I receiving this error, and if appropriate, where is my logic mistaken?

I at first thought this was a CORS error but am not receiving a CORS error message in google console.

Comment: Please don't send credentials via URL query parameters, it's extremely insecure

Comment: Your request is probably being canceled due to navigation. You need to prevent the default _submit_ event action, eg `function submit(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: It's most likely happening because your button is of type `submit`, so it executes the default action. 

You can remove the type and add an onClick to handle the request **but you should definitely change the way you receive your email/password from the frontend**. 

It's safer to send your credentials as an object body as opposed to query parameters so you should modify your backend logic to handle that instead.